# Can xfce4-screenshotter be configured to save a screenshot without any GUI appearing?

Tags: screenshot, xfce, xubuntu, ubuntu-20.04, xfce4

I quite like xfce4-screenshooter, but even when I map it to my prntscrn key and tell it where to save e.g. `xfce4-screenshooter --fullscreen --save ~/Pictures/Screenshots/`, the GUI still appears to asks me to give a filename. Is there any way to make it not ask?

Similar questions exist, e.g. [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/22555/824054), but they do not appear to be specific to xfce4-screenshooter.

Comment: I have xfce4 screenshot here on my Kali Machine here. The GUI tool needs to know where to save things, so I am pretty sure the answer to your question is NO.  Every app that saves stuff needs to know where. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @John I've already told it where to save, but the GUI pops up because it needs a filename. I want to make it not ask for that. In other words, I need to automatically give it a file name.

Comment: Try this   https://askubuntu.com/questions/306689/making-a-screenshot-in-xfce#:~:text=3%20Answers&text=Go%20to%3A,order%20to%20take%20fullscreen%20screenshots.

Comment: @John That's equivalent to what I've already done.

Comment: So you probably cannot do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to take and save a screenshot without showing the GUI, xfce4-screenshot needs to be provided with the full path at which the screenshot should be saved, including the name of the file it should be saved as well as the folder it should be saved in.

You can provide it with this by generating a filename based on the current date using the command:

```
xfce4-screenshooter --fullscreen --save ~/Pictures/Screenshots/"Screenshot $(date -d "today" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M").png"
```

This should automatically take a screenshot and then save it as e.g. `Screenshot 2021-12-01 00:00.png` in `~/Pictures/Screenshots`.

If you wish to activate this command via a keyboard shortcut, this will not work directly since it has to be run in a shell (e.g. bash), however, you should be able to create a shell script with the above command (by copying the command into a .sh file and making it executable) which you can then configure to execute for your chosen keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Very close to perfect. This saves a screenshot without the GUI appearing, but the full name of the resulting screenshot is the text that you've given after the final forward slash. In other words, `$(date -d "today" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")` is not being evaluated.

Comment: The latest edit to this answer has resolved this issue. Just make a script and point the keyboard shortcut to it.

Answer (score 1):

With the `--save` option, the GUI should not be launched.

To control the saved file-name,
there are two settings that you can add to the
xfce4-screenshooter config file, `~/.config/xfce4/xfce4-screenshooter`,
which will allow you to change the default filename:

```
title=<YOUR_TITLE_HERE>
timestamp=<TRUE_OR_FALSE>
```

The `title` parameter will change the first part of the filename
(defaults to "Screenshot") and `timestamp` will turn on or off the
appending of the timestamp after the filename.

If you turn off the timestamp, the program is smart enough to append a
`-1`, `-2`, `-3` etc to the end of the filename,
if a file exists with that name already.